# Spring Boot OAuth2 OAuth2Authentication vs UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am having problem to get a proper response from the REST controller that is used to send user details back. Using Spring Boot 1.5.10. Here is the setup:

1. OAuth2 project to serve as authentication and authorization endpoint
2. Microservices that connect to the server to authenticate and authorize

OAuth server is using **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** (order 2), **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** (to secure api other than oauth), **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter** (oauth config) and **GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter** (ldap vs database auth).

I have a resource /api/v1/me to return Principal/Authentication object in both OAuth server and a microservice. Microservice is behaving correctly and returns OAuth2Authentication when a proper Bearer token is present or 401 if not (Token can be obtained from the OAuth server).

OAuth server, on the other hand, is giving me some issues. It returns **/me** response only when I request a token first (establish a JSession) or forwards me to the login page if not. (I am using **authorization_code** grant with Thymeleaf). In this case I get UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

Is it possible to configure the server to use Bearer to authenticate **/me** and return OAuth2Authentication or 401 vs the Java session on OAuth server itself that I need only to get the token itself via username auth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, after a day of searching after I post my question I found a lead ([here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)). The key was in how http was configured, where before I was including antMatchers with permitAll for those I did not want to authenticate, and I needed actually to .requestMatchers().antMatchers to include only resources I was interested in + "/login", "/oauth/authorize" inside the web adapter. Resource adapter should pick up the rest.